# Modernzr mq is undefined?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, modernizr

So getting an error in console :"Uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.on is not a function"

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {
    console.log('Something!');
   } else {
    console.log('Something else!');
   }
}).resize();
```

Basically wanted to apply some different code on different wdith lengths and modernizr was said to support IE9 as well so I thought I use this but alas it's not working.

That being said I'm a beginner so thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: Which version of Modernizr are you using? The documentation suggests that `Modernizr.on` is a relatively new feature.

Comment: @Juhana I have modernizr-2.8.3

Comment: That's pretty old. The latest is 3.3.1. The problem will probably get solved by updating.

Comment: Yeah that was it, consol displayed the message but for some weird reason the whole page turned completely white - not sure what's that about.